# CSS Media Query breakpoints

Tags: css, media-queries, screen-size

just a quick question.
What is the best set for css breakpoints?

Right now I'm using this one:

```
min 1200px
max 1200px
max 900px
max 600px
max 480px
max 320px
```

Anyway there is a problem with the min 1200px because the differents between a 1200px and a 1800px screen are huge.

Comment: there is no best set of breakpoints. Some website don't even need a single media query

Answer (score 0):

From [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_media_query_breakpoints.asp)

> There are tons of screens and devices with different heights and widths, so it is hard to create an exact breakpoint for each device. To keep things simple you could target five common groups:

```
/* Extra small devices (phones, 600px and down) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {...}

/* Small devices (portrait tablets and large phones, 600px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {...}

/* Medium devices (landscape tablets, 768px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {...}

/* Large devices (laptops/desktops, 992px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {...}

/* Extra large devices (large laptops and desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {...}
```

Answer (score -1):

Bootstrap breakpoints are very standard. You can use these breakpoints.

```
// X-Small devices (portrait phones, less than 576px)
// No media query for `xs` since this is the default in Bootstrap

// Small devices (landscape phones, 576px and up)
@media (min-width: 576px) { ... }

// Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up)
@media (min-width: 768px) { ... }

// Large devices (desktops, 992px and up)
@media (min-width: 992px) { ... }

// X-Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up)
@media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }

// XX-Large devices (larger desktops, 1400px and up)
@media (min-width: 1400px) { ... }
```

[Read more about that](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/layout/breakpoints/)

Answer (score -1):

You can visit this site [Overview](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/overview/)

```
// Small devices (landscape phones, 576px and up)
@media (min-width: 576px) { ... }

// Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up)
@media (min-width: 768px) { ... }

// Large devices (desktops, 992px and up)
@media (min-width: 992px) { ... }

// Extra large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up)
@media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }
```